# How can I improve a "dumb" vector quantization algorithm for K-means clustering

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, cluster-analysis, k-means

I need to convert a codebase relying on the scipy.cluster.vq module to not use scipy so that I can implement it in C++.

First I am trying to replicate the results using only numpy.

Starting with an image of dimensions MxNx3 , I create a "centroids" Kx3 array using kmeans with opencv.

I need to map each pixel of the original image to the pixel value in the centroids array that is closest to the original pixel.

I have it working, but performance is awful. I'm sure there must be more advanced ways to compute this, and I suspect it's related to a nearest neighbour search (maybe?) but don't know for sure.

Here is what I'm currently doing: I think this may be called a "brute force" approach

1. iterate over every pixel in the image
2. calculate the euclidean distance between this pixel and each pixel in the centroid list
3. return the minimum value from the list generated in step 2
4. assign the original image pixel to the value of the centroids list that returned the minimum distance.

   ```
   def vq(self,image,centroids):
       x,y,z = image.shape
       Z=np.reshape(image,(x*y,z))
       counts = np.zeros(len(centroids))
       clusterMap = np.zeros(Z.shape,np.uint8)
       for i in range(Z.shape[0]):
           color = Z[i]
           closestIndex = self.getClosestCenter(color, centroids)
           counts[closestIndex]+=1# tracking how often each color occurs
           clusterMap[i] = centroids[closestIndex]
       return clusterMap,counts

   def getClosestCenter(self,color,centers):
           distances = [0 for i in range(len(centers))]
           for i,center in enumerate(centers):
               distances[i] = self.getDistance(color, center)
           return distances.index(min(distances))

   def getDistance(self,value1,value2):
          if len(value1) !=len(value2): return None #error
           sum = 0
           for i in range(len(value1)):
               sum+=(value1[i]-value2[i])**2
           return sum**(0.5)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *profile your code* to see where exactly it is slow.
Constructs such as `enumerate` can be very expensive because they require the creation and garbage collection of many tuple objects. A good rule of thumb is to avoid object allocations in inner loops and functions (this includes hidden objects such as tuples)

Last but not least, kmeans does *not* use Euclidean distance. It uses sum-of-squares. Get rid of the square root.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

So instead of using `enumerate`, it will be better to just increment an `int` manually?


For the last point, This method is not computing the K-means, but is using the values from k-means to re-map the pixels of the original image to the centers returned from kmeans.


However, I just realized opencv returns a `label` map that has the exact data I need, so all I have to do is perform a histogram on that matrix to get the relative counts of each centroid.

Comment: Remapping would also use the least-squares approach.